# What is the value of a WebAssembly local that has not been set?

Tags: initialization, undefined, webassembly, specifications, local-variables

If I use `local.get` to access the value of a WebAssembly local which I have not already set via `local.set` or `local.tee`, am I guaranteed to get a specific default value, or is this undefined behavior? For instance:

```
(module
  (func (result i32) (local i32)
    local.get 0))
```

Running this in Chrome gives zero, but I would like to know if that is guaranteed by the spec.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, the Wasm spec demands that all local variables are zero initialized. Thus you'd get the same behavior on all spec compliant runtimes.

You can find this in the spec here: https://webassembly.github.io/spec/core/exec/instructions.html#exec-invoke